# Change Oracle SQL Query Text before submission

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

Is there a advanced oracle feature to modify the SQL Query just before it is submitted to oracle? Or may be modify the result set? Based on certain condition? Like may be based on the name of the process that submits the query? Or based on the query text?

The scenario is that a process (written in C++) is running a query and we don't have a way to change the C++ code. A particular business validation within that process is failing and in order to make the validation not fail, I want a way to manipulate the returned data set or manipulate the select query just before it is submitted to oracle engine.

The C++ code is running this exact query

SELECT PL_ID FROM A_HDR WHERE ENT_NBR=''

I want to change it such that ORACLE always sees and executes the following query instead

SELECT NULL FROM A_HDR WHERE ENT_NBR=''

Please guide

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific about the problem you're trying to solve. What exactly are you trying to change, and how?

Comment: The problem is that a business process is failing for a validation. The process is written in C++ and we don't have a way to change the C++ code as the vendor has disappeared. Now in order to make the validation not fail, I want a way to manipulate the returned data set or manipulate the select query just before it is submitted to oracle engine. I know this is a long shot but trying to find a way out.

Comment: Still too vague. When I said "be more specific", I meant actual code samples, e.g. something like "The C++ code is trying to run this query `SELECT a FROM b WHERE c`, I want to change it to `...?...`"

Comment: The C++ code is running this query... SELECT PL_ID FROM A_HDR WHERE ENT_NBR='<NUMBER>'....I want to change it such that ORACLE always sees executes SELECT NULL FROM A_HDR WHERE ENT_NBR='<NUMBER>' instead....

Comment: In that case, VPD will not be able to help you. You might be able to handle this by creating a synonym `A_HDR` that points to a view on the `A_HDR` table, that returns `NULL` instead of `PL_ID`.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey...That information helps. I would appreciate if you could unmark the flag that this question is not a "Real Question". May be i was not clear or did not provide enough information at the beginning but that was not my intention. I did my research and this was something more advanced and hence could not find this on my own. The intent was always right though. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: You may also want to look into [DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE](http://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/optimizing-unoptimizeable-sql-dbms_advanced_rewrite/).  That can sometimes be used to change the values from a query, instead of just the rows returned.  Although I'm not sure if you could make it work differently for each user.  You may need to combine VPD with rewrite, to both identify and change the queries.  That's a horrible solution, but it sounds like you're in a tough situation.  Maybe intercepting the query in the driver would be better, although I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Thanks jonearles....That's a gem of a information.

Comment: @Guddu, the "not a real question" flag is about the wording of this question, nothing personal. In its current form, this question is not likely to be of much help to others - but with a bit of editing it might be made more useful; then we might reopen.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey...I do understand that. I have done a edit. Please see if the edit is worth having the question reopen. I am banned from posting further questions and I hope to get that ban lifted soon. I will be more careful in posting my questions and providing good information up-front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm#DBSEG007) may be what you're looking for.  From the manual:

> Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD) enables you to create security
>   policies to control database access at the row and column level.
>   Essentially, Oracle Virtual Private Database adds a dynamic WHERE
>   clause to a SQL statement that is issued against the table, view, or
>   synonym to which an Oracle Virtual Private Database security policy
>   was applied.

You may be able to get the process and query text from [SYS_CONTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions184.htm).  For example, `sys_context('userenv', 'current_sql')` and `sys_context('userenv', 'module')`.  You may also need to use `GV$SESSION` to get more information.

However, I think you should try to avoid VPD if possible.  It is *extremely* confusing to have all your SQL statements silently converted in the background.  It can make development and troubleshooting very difficult.

---

**Update**

The [SQL Translation Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/gateways.121/e22508/sql_transl_arch.htm#DRDAA131) feature in Oracle 12c would probably be the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Thanks Jones...SYS_CONTEXT is a new information for me and will help me going forward in my application.

Comment: I have been banned from asking more questions on StackOverflow just because of all the negatives that i received for this question. I sincerely feel that it is a bit harsh on me as I asked or intended to ask the question in best way possible. I have provided all logical details since and I request you folks to help me out remove the ban for me.

Comment: @Guddu I'm surprised that you've been banned.  Some of your questions have some issues, but that's not unusual.  Sorry to say that I may have been part of the problem; I down-voted one of your questions, but you later updated the question and fixed the issue.  I removed the down vote a few days ago, hopefully that will undo your ban?  If not, I guess you should look on Meta for advice.  I also voted to re-open, but I've never seen a question get re-opened.

Comment: @Guddu Is this question still unresolved?  If so, feel free to un-accept my answer.  My answer doesn't seem correct anymore, for the updated version.  Maybe a solution involving some of the previous comments would work better.