# How to restrict query for oracle with specific conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I want to know if there is a way to specify a condition on a table, I mean I need to restrict queries under certain conditions such as status so that I don't have to rewrite the status condition within all the select queries that I already have in my application.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to constrain the contents of your tables to satisfy a condition, or are you looking for a shortcut for writing queries?

Comment: yes, i want to avoid coding conditions that every sql query that i have  coded must have,i know of this functionality on DBMSII but i dont know  how to achieve this for an oracle table

Comment: Oracle Virtual Private Database may be the solution, depending on why you are looking to do this.  This may be a duplicate of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12945957/409172).

Comment: Well the first choice is not what i am looking  for, the second choice is more what i want and its something that i considered but it would be too troublesome for me to make that many views,so that is why i was looking into a way to make that once a record was changed to a certain condition it was not able to be retrieved by any other query. i hope i can get across the idea better now.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main alternatives:

1. You can apply constraints to the base tables that enforce the condition(s) in question.  This limits the data that can reside in the tables, but if you literally *never* want to execute a query that does not include a given condition, then there is no point in storing any data in your table that fails to satisfy the condition.
2. You can create views in your database that filter your base tables by the condition in question, and write your queries in terms of these views.  That does not constrain the contents of the base tables, but it provides a shortcut for writing queries.

I asked you (less verbosely) in comments which you wanted, and you said "yes".  I therefore present a bit of detail on both alternatives.

In Oracle, the syntax for creating a table constraint follows this pattern:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT [optional_constraint_name]
    CHECK (<condition(s)>);
```

In Oracle, the syntax for creating a view such as you might want follows this pattern:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE <conditions>;
```

Choose whichever approach meets your need, and consult the docs for full details on the corresponding statement.